# Trouble with script getting last action using nested queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using a database where every Order has an Item assigned to it and every Item has to have a Start action before a Work action can occur to it, and once it's done a Finish action is carried out.

There can be multiple Starts and Finishes on the same Item but Work can only be carried out between a Start and a Finish action.

I've written a script to try and find any cases of Work being carried out after a Finish but without a Start but it doesn't return the values that I want.

```
SELECT
O.ORDER_NUMBER
--,*
FROM
[CUSTOMER] [C]
JOIN
[SITE] [S] ON C.CUSTOMER_ID=S.CUSTOMER_ID
JOIN
[ORDER] [O] ON S.SITE_ID=O.SITE_ID
JOIN
[ITEM] [I] ON O.ORDER_ID=I.ORDER_ID
JOIN
(SELECT
    MAX(ACTION_ID) AS [START_ID]
    ,A2.ITEM_ID
FROM
    [ACTION] [A2]
JOIN
    [ALLOWED_ACTION] [AA2] ON A2.ALLOWED_ACTION_ID = AA2.ALLOWED_ACTION_ID
WHERE
    AA2.DESCRIPTION='START'
GROUP BY
    A2.ITEM_ID) AS [D] ON I.ITEM_ID=D.ITEM_ID
JOIN
(SELECT
    MAX(ACTION_ID) AS [FINISH_ID]
    ,A3.ITEM_ID
FROM
    [ACTION] [A3]
JOIN
    [ALLOWED_ACTION] [AA3] ON A3.ALLOWED_ACTION_ID = AA3.ALLOWED_ACTION_ID
WHERE
    AA3.DESCRIPTION='FINISH'
GROUP BY
    A3.ITEM_ID) AS [F] ON I.ITEM_ID=F.ITEM_ID
JOIN
(SELECT
    MAX(ACTION_ID) AS [LAST_ID]
    ,A4.ITEM_ID
FROM
    [ACTION] [A4]
GROUP BY
    A4.ITEM_ID) AS [L] ON I.ITEM_ID=L.ITEM_ID
WHERE
(L.LAST_ID>F.FINISH_ID)
AND 
(F.FINISH_ID>D.START_ID)
```

I've taken a look at [How to get the 2nd highest from a table where it need to be added first in sql server in a single query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929650/how-to-get-the-2nd-highest-from-a-table-where-it-need-to-be-added-first-in-sql-s) and others like it to try and figure it out but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

A typical result would get me an Order Number and when I check the actions the last action is always a Finish or it has a Start first.

Any help would mean a lot to me.

Comment: If this is a `greatest-n-per-group` problem, you could try [searching the site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql-server "[greatest-n-per-group] + [sql-server]") for ready solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a work-around to this problem.

I got all the information into a temporary table and then did the final conditional statement on the temporary table and it called in the information that I wanted.

Not sure if the original conditional statement was only working on a part of the script or not but it'll have to take someone smarter than me to figure that out :)

Anyway, here's the final script that worked for me.

```
SELECT
O.ORDER_NUMBER
,LAST_ID
,FINISH_ID
,LAST_ID
INTO #TEMP1
--,*
FROM [CUSTOMER] [C]
JOIN [SITE] [S] ON C.CUSTOMER_ID=S.CUSTOMER_ID
JOIN [ORDER] [O] ON S.SITE_ID=O.SITE_ID
JOIN [ITEM] [I] ON O.ORDER_ID=I.ORDER_ID
JOIN (SELECT
    MAX(ACTION_ID) AS [START_ID], A2.ITEM_ID
    FROM [ACTION] [A2]
    JOIN [ALLOWED_ACTION] [AA2] ON A2.ALLOWED_ACTION_ID = AA2.ALLOWED_ACTION_ID
    WHERE AA2.DESCRIPTION='START'
    GROUP BY A2.ITEM_ID) AS [D] ON I.ITEM_ID=D.ITEM_ID
JOIN (SELECT
    MAX(ACTION_ID) AS [FINISH_ID], A3.ITEM_ID
    FROM [ACTION] [A3]
    JOIN [ALLOWED_ACTION] [AA3] ON A3.ALLOWED_ACTION_ID = AA3.ALLOWED_ACTION_ID
    WHERE AA3.DESCRIPTION='FINISH'
    GROUP BY A3.ITEM_ID) AS [F] ON I.ITEM_ID=F.ITEM_ID
JOIN (SELECT
    MAX(ACTION_ID) AS [LAST_ID], A4.ITEM_ID
    FROM [ACTION] [A4]
    GROUP BY A4.ITEM_ID) AS [L] ON I.ITEM_ID=L.ITEM_ID

SELECT ORDER_NUMBER FROM #TEMP1
WHERE LAST_ID>FINISH_ID
AND 
FINISH_ID>START_ID
```